# Optimize Delphi Reading Records From File

Tags: delphi, record

I would like to optimize the reading from a file where I have records that contains (to make it easy) a datetime, and some values.

The records are sorted in the file (the older one is at the beginning of the file and the most recent at the end). The file could be really big and the user can choose a date range of the data he wants to load.

The datas are displayed in a StringGrid

I want to optimize the reading to make it as faster as possible.

Any help ?

The code above not working when the first records are not on the date range selected by the user

```pascal
Type TlFab = Record
               Value1 : SmallInt;
               Value2 : SmallInt;     
               Value3 : String[10];
               date   : TDateTime;
             End;

Var TabRecords    : Array Of TlFab;

Procedure LoadRecordsFromFile(Sender : Tobject);


Var f        : File;   
    PtrBuf,
    Buf      : ^TlFab;

    i,
    Index,
    PosFile,
    NToRead,
    NReaded        : Integer;

    NbRecords     : Integer;
    i   : Integer;

    SearchFinished : Boolean;

Begin

  AssignFile(f, 'test.bin');
{$I-}
  FileMode := fmOpenRead;
  Reset(f, SizeOf(Buf^));
  FileMode := fmOpenReadWrite;
{$I+}

  If (IoResult <> 0) Then
  Begin
    MessageDlg('Error', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  End;

  i := 0;                 
  NbRecords := Filesize(f);     

  SetLength(TabRecords, NbRecords); 


  NToRead := 65000 Div SizeOf(Buf^);
  GetMem(Buf, Word(NToRead * SizeOF(Buf^)));
  PtrBuf := Buf;
  PosFile := Filesize(f);

  SearchFinished:= FALSE;

  Repeat
  Begin
    NReaded := 0;
    PosFile := PosFile - NToRead;
    If(PosFile < 0) Then
    Begin
      NToRead := NToRead + PosFile; 
      PosFile := 0;
    End;

    Seek(f,PosFile);

    Buf := PtrBuf;
    BlockRead(f,Buf^, NToRead, NReaded);

    Inc(Buf, Pred(NReaded));


    For Index := NReaded Downto 1 Do
    Begin
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        TabRecords[i].DateFin := Buf^.date;

        If (TabRecords[i].DateFin > DateTimePickerDateFin.DateTime)    Or
           (TabRecords[i].DateFin < DateTimePickerDateDebut.DateTime)  Then
        Begin
          SearchFinished := TRUE;
        End

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        TabRecords[i].Value1        := Buf^.Value1;
        TabRecords[i].Value2        := Buf^.Value2;
        TabRecords[i].Value3        := Buf^.Value3 - i - 1; //** Real position in the file

        Inc(i);

        Dec(Buf);
      End;
  End
  Until (i >= NbRecords) Or
        (NReaded < NToRead) Or
        (PosFile = 0) Or
        SearchFinished;

  SetLength(TabRecords, i); 
  
  CloseFile(f);       
  FreeMem(PtrBuf);
End;
```

Comment: Without your code so far nobody can say what needs to be improved.

Comment: Rethink your UX, nobody needs a StringGrid with 100000 lines of data to scroll through.

Comment: @AmigoJack I updated with code

Comment: @Kromster I need help to avoid this and only fill the Stringgrid only with the data that the user asks (with DateTimePicker)

Comment: I have three suggestions: 1.) Create an index file which tells you which date starts at which position in the file, so you don't have to search through the file each time. 2.) If the file is really big with lots of data, better split the file and start a new file every day/week/month 3.) Use a file of TfFab and you get rid of calculating positions.

Comment: 1) How this can help ? What do you put on the file and how to you search on it ?
2) I'm able to read 170 records with BlockRead and the file could go up to 10Mb
3) I have to go through each record in this case ?

Comment: I would certainly not use a StringGrid with so many records. A ListView in report view and virtual mode would be much more efficient and cleaner-looking. And you wouldn't even have to keep all of the records in memory at one time, you can load records dynamically as the user scrolls through the ListView. I use this approach to display large log files with million of records, and it works well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The Stringgrid is not my issue. And I need it as I also have filters on the other fields of the records. I need to put in memory the records asked by the user (with date range) and after this he is able to filter by fields of the records.

Comment: If I understand your code you are reading from the end of the file toward the beginning. That could hurt performance quite a bit since you are not benefiting anything for hard drive cache. You should instead be reading from the beginning of the file toward the end which is also commonly known as sequential reading. Sequential reading of data is a lot faster since it allows hard drive to actually read some more data into it's cache even thou you haven't requested it with your current read command. But when you request a next read command hard drive could then deliver that data from cache

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes I'm doing this as the data that the user search have a very high probability to be at the end of the file (most recent datas). When the form is shown to the use, we display the record of the last day and after this he can search by himself with DateTimePicker on old datas.

Comment: NOTE: when doing sequential reading you wont need to use `Seek` command to update your file position after each read since `BlockRead` already moves file position according to the amount of data it has read. So for instance if you used `BlockRead` to read first five records in the file. You don't need to manually update file position using `Seek` but instead just call `Blockread` again to read next five records from a file.

Comment: In order to avoid the need to iterate through the whole file you could make use of [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in order to find first record that contains the oldest date the user chosen in his selection. And also the latest for that matter. So eventually you can use Binary Search to determine range exact portion of the file that you need to read in order to return desired results to your user.

Comment: @Nizarazu in my ListView log viewer, I use a memory-mapped view of the raw file data, sliding that up and down the file as needed. And I have 3 memory buffers holding just the records that match the user's filter - one for the first N records, one for the last N records, and one for the on-screen records. I match those up to ListView items. As the user scrolls through the ListView, the memory view slides and updates the onscreen buffer as needed. Works very well, and very fast, especially when using the cache hints provided by the ListView

Comment: Why don't you just use an embedded DB like e.g. SQLite?